# Is this question fitting in this section?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Assume the following table. I want to partition it in a way that it never happens to have elements from Field1 and Field2 which are "connected" (i.e. a and 1, a and 2, b and 1) go to a separate partition.

This is the solution with 3 partitions.

```
ab12, c3, d45
```

Is this kind or problems related to data science? On which section could I place it?

```
+--------+--------+
| Field1 | Field2 |
+--------+--------+
| a      | 1      |
+--------+--------+
| a      | 2      |
+--------+--------+
| b      | 1      |
+--------+--------+
| b      | 2      |
+--------+--------+
| c      | 3      |
+--------+--------+
| d      | 4      |
+--------+--------+
| d      | 5      |
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly on topic. You should ask it. I like it a lot.

Comment: done: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185410/finding-the-partitions-of-a-set-which-respect-to-some-rules and thanks!